# UIWebView in UITableViewCell getting refreshed while scrolling

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, hyperlink, uilabel

I've a custom UITableViewCell with UIWebview to display the hyperlink text in user's activity (ref. attached image).UIWebView generally takes a sec to load HTML data. Also during scrolling, UIWebView will get refreshed again and it take a sec more, which looks very odd.

I tried [FancyLabel](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/), but not able to achieve the same result.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `NSAttributedString` for this problem. Follow the mentioned links :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1487/_index.html
http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/358-How-to-make-a-clickable-link-inside-a-NSTextField-and-Cocoa

You can also try `CoreText`, but it comes with the overhead of coding in `drawRect`:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/