# Have different color and different font size in one label

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am recently learning iOS development, i am wondering if that is possible to have one label with different size, different fonts and different colors, such as

**user name(blue, bolder, and large font)** is watching **walking dead (red, bolder and medium font)** on **xxxx site (blue, bolder and large font)**

Thanks!

Comment: for that you have to used NSAttributedString.

Comment: Please, before posting, have a look at the related questions that SO shows you. Or do some searching first.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/12853645/501487

Comment: NSAttributedString is the way to go. If you're trying for iOS7 alone, check out TextKit. It gives you great capabilities. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. xib file or storyboard

   go the label, and choose attribute instead of plain
   [image]

   then do whatever you want there
   [image]
2. codes

   ```
   NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"user name is watching walking dead on xxx site"];

       [attributedString addAttributes:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       NSFontAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"WHATEVER FONT" size:FONT_SIZE_HERE],
                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor blueColor],
                                       nil]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, 9)];//9 is the length of "user name"

       [attributedString addAttributes:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                NSFontAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"WHATEVER FONT" size:FONT_SIZE_HERE],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor blueColor],
                                nil]
                         range:NSMakeRange(22, 12)];//22 is the start index of "Walking dead"
                                                    //and 12 is the length of "Walking dead"

   //you got the idea, same way to do the xxx site.
   //Check a file called "NSAttributedString.h" 
   //you will find even more options there
   ```

I personally prefer the second solution, since you have more options in the code, and it works for pretty much all the cases. But there is a learning curve.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to use [`NSMutableAttributedString`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"monkey goat"];        
UILabel *testingLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
testingLbl.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 30);
[attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor redColor] range: NSMakeRange(0,6)];                
[attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] range: NSMakeRange(0,6)];        
[attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:24] range: NSMakeRange(7,4)];        
testingLbl.attributedText  = attString;
[self.view addSubview:testingLbl];
```

And also this is the best site for find any custom controllers, Bye the way in your case fine [`UILabel`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UILabel) with source code: